# Mysql:How to get a S-lock in a Transaction

Tags: mysql

I tried to get a S-lock using following SQL:

```
start transaction;
  SELECT * FROM test.t1 where id=1;
```

But I found this way does not work. I changed it as following:

```
start transaction;
  SELECT * FROM test.t1 where id=1 lock in share mode;
```

I am wondering why the first way does not get a S-lock?

I already set `autocommit=0;`

Comment: I think they are not being locked by default on select. By the way, here is some interesting information about it : http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/07/31/innodb-table-locks/

Comment: thank u @mareckmareck , But when will the S-lock be granted without using 'lock in share mode'?

Comment: Is test.t1 innodb table?

Comment: Yes,test.t1 is a innodb table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On tables, InnoDB normally acquires only intentional shared (LOCK_IS) or intentional exclusive (LOCK_IX) modes. It does not lock the tables in shared mode (LOCK_S) or exclusive mode (LOCK_X) unless explicitly requested via LOCK TABLES command.

As stated [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysqlinnodb/entry/introduction_to_transaction_locks_in) in "Table Level Transaction Locks" section (I presumed that your table is InnoDB).

As for answer to your comment about when the shared lock is granted, it is in the same article in another line:

> One exception to this is in the prepare phase of the online alter table command, where the table is locked in shared mode

Comment: Thank u @mareckmareck , I ask a new question which related to this,could u pls look at it ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926127/mysqllock-in-transaction